# OpenMaya API (python or C++): Given string with DAG name or path, get MDagPath

Tags: c++, python, maya

Test case:
Maya 2014, New scene, create polygonal plane.
Result is a plane named "pPlane1".

If I know the name of an object, here "pPlane1", I want an OpenMaya (OM) MDagPath instance, so that I can pass it to other OM methods.

This works (python), but it requires modifying the selection, and seems cumbersome:

```
import maya.OpenMaya as om        # Version 1
from maya.OpenMaya import MGlobal as omg

# Returns [dagPath]. If none, returns [].
def GetDag(name):
    omg.clearSelectionList()
    omg.selectByName(name)
    selectionList = om.MSelectionList()
    omg.getActiveSelectionList(selectionList)
    #
    iterator = om.MItSelectionList( selectionList, om.MFn.kDagNode )
    dagPath = om.MDagPath()
    result = []
    if not iterator.isDone():
        iterator.getDagPath( dagPath )
        result = [dagPath]
    return result

# ---------- Testing ----------
name = "pPlane1"
result = GetDag(name)
if len(result) > 0:
    dagPath = result[0]
    ...
```

Is there an easier way?  Have I overlooked some class or method in OM?

NOTE: I'm not using pymel, because "import pymel.core as pm" results in an error on my system. That is a question for Autodesk's forums. For now, my goal is to learn to use OpenMaya APIs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to use the global selection list, you can create an MSelectionList for the purpose of getting the dag only:

```
def DagNode ( xform ):
    selectionList = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
    try:
        selectionList.add( xform )
    except:
        return None
    dagPath = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
    selectionList.getDagPath( 0, dagPath )
    return dagPath
```

Comment: Thanks - that is what I was missing: I didn't understand what MSelectionList class was capable of. I didn't know you could create a query like that. Most importantly, I didn't know about the add method that accepted a string argument. How did you learn this? Recommend tutorials, websites, books?

Comment: I don't recall exactly, I think I picked it up from Ryan Trowbridge's site.  Tech-artists.org and the Google group "python inside maya" are both good resources

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve It is mentioned also in the maya api manual examples, as well as the manual entries themselves. Even if they are c you will get how to use maya in a more general way from that resource. I mean, I couldnt use **maya.OpenMayaRender** 15 minutes ago. Yet now I do and have allready made a rudimentary ray tracer.

Comment: NOTE: I tried adding a change to this post's code, to wrap selectionList.getDagPath in try/except and return None. This fixes an exception that occurred for me, and matches theodox's intent (observe that he does the exact same thing for an exception in selectionList.add. This simple, correct, and necessary change was rejected by @Adi_Inbar, Huangism, and 1_CR. I can only assume that none of them are experienced MAYA python programmers. (Two more experienced programmers, Devon_C_Miller and PearsonArtPhoto did approve it, but that was not enough for it to take effect. Thanks guys.)